# Different date format (input or just display of text)

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-blade

I have 2 fields (started_at and ends_at), and I want to format them

For that, I use this accessor :

```
public function getStartedAtAttribute($value): string
{
  return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
}
```

This is working for input with "\T" but not working for simple text

If I remove "\T", this is not working for input (type = datetimelocal)

How can I differentiate input or simple text ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: why not just user `$yourModel->started_at->format('Y-m-d\TH:i')` for datetimelocal text and `$yourModel->started_at->format('Y-m-d')` for simple test

Comment: I have many places with dates, I would like to centralize everything in the model

Comment: I think your have the wrong approach, the blade template (The view) should format the date according with the text component.

Comment: I agree with you, you are right. I will do so with a ->format(). Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the default format date on your model by using the cast array

```
protected $casts = [
    'started_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

Comment: Yes but this is not working on input ? and I can't duplicate this line and change datetime to datetime-local